# edit hosts file to test an intranet site

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012, hosts

I am hosting a Production site on a new production server, currently the site is running on old production server. After completing the deployment on new server, i want to test it before it can go live(DNS switching from old server to new server).

Assume, live URL of site is for e.g. `abc.com`

so, currently `abc.com` is pointing to old server and `abc.com` is also on new server.
DNS switching will be done to get `abc.com` from new server.

But, before getting live i want to test the new server `abc.com` that everything is fine.

So, i am trying to make an entry in my machine hosts file like `192.168.1.1 abc.com` where 192.168.1.1 is my new server IP address.

Now, from my machine when i `ping abc.com` it shows new server IP(192.168.1.1).

But, in browser it shows `File or directory not found.`

When i enable the Directory browsing in IIS it shows the directories and then files in it but when i click on any file it again says `File or directory not found.`

Comment: Do you have the right [default document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) configured in IIS?  You may have a check on the IIS log to see what is the status/sub-status code, and then refer to [this MSKB](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/943891) to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet explorer it worked properly. No changes required. I was testing in Mozilla and surprisingly, it doesn't worked.